# Incluir librerias que están en el path de windows

Tags: c++, qt-creator

Esta es mi duda. Ahora que me he actualizado a python 3.9, éste se instala por defecto en:

```
C:\Users\minombredeusuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39
```

Esta ruta está en el `path` de windows.

Esto lo tengo que llevar a una aplicación en Qt. Así que he de definir esta ruta en mi archivo `*.pro`:

```
win32 {
    INCLUDEPATH += C:\Users\minombredeusuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\include    
    LIBS += -L C:\Users\minombredeusuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\libs -lpython39
    DEPENDPATH += C:\Users\minombredeusuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\include    
}
```

Y me preguntaba si, al estar esta ruta definida en el path de windows, si habría una forma "corta" de indicar estas rutas.

Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Puede crear un symlink con MKLINK

```
mklink /d c:\py C:\Users\minombredeusuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\include
```

entonces refiere a c:\py .